# How can I send a POST request in C ++ without using sockets

Tags: c++, python-3.x, http, post, http-post

I have python code that sends a POST request and gets a json, I need to rewrite it in C ++ (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019). I don’t understand what tools can really do everything I need without complicating the code.

There will be a console application that must send a request to send or receive data, more precisely a video stream. 
I read about Boost.Asio, but it seems to work only with sockets, is there any way without them? At first I wanted to use it, as the most famous. I read about сurl, but it hasn't been updated for a long time, is it still relevant?

```py
    headers_predict = {
        "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Session-ID": session_id
        }
    data_predict = {
      "audio": {
          "data": sound_base64,
          "mime": "audio/pcm16"
          },
      "package_id": ""
      }
    url = 'https://cp.speechpro.com/recognize'
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers_predict, 
    data=json.dumps(data_predict))
    print('Response: %s' % r.text)
```

I wouldn't want to use sockets, because I don't understand them.
I need to be able to set the header and data as a json.

Comment: Use curl: https://curl.haxx.se

Comment: A socket is the combination of IP address and port number. Nearly all network communication nowadays works with sockets. Probably there is no way to communicate with a web server without sockets, even using python. And yes, curl is still relevant.

Comment: _"hasn't been updated for a long time"_ doesn't necessarily mean bad

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand that it is impossible without sockets. I just don’t want to make a mistake in the settings, so I don’t want to describe them myself, but use a ready-made interface. Then there will be a curl

Answer (score 3):

> sockets, is there any way without them?

Technically, HTTP does not specify the underlying transport protocol and it can work with any sort of streaming transport. You could for example write the request into a file.

But, if you currently use TCP and don't want to change that, then you must use sockets. You don't need to interact with them directly if you use an existing HTTP client library.